# Extract part of the string

Tags: javascript, jquery, string, match

I need to extract part of the string while looks like this for example:

```
01.&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Artist Name - Song Title
```

So I have counter at the beginning, dot and a separator can be anything, currenty separator is:

```
var separator = &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
```

I want to extract everything after separator.

Using jquery/javascript.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Just split the string on the separator and pop of the last part :

```
var lastPart = str.split(separator).pop();
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/wxT8M/1/)

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan - Thanks! Yup, `shift()` and `pop()` come in handy sometimes.

Answer (score 1):

You could try to use [String.split](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split), but I'd suggest using [String.indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf) and [String.substring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring) to find the first offset of your separator and then select the rest of the string.  Using [String.split](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) could fail if your name and song title contains the separator internally.

You could also write a [regex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) to split the arguments, which would let you extract the artist and song title separately.

To use indexOf:

```
var str = "01.&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Artist Name - Song Title";
var sep = "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;"
var artist_title = str.substring(str.indexOf(sep) + sep.length);
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = artist_title;
```

To use a regex:

```
var str = "01.&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Artist Name - Song Title";
var regex = /(\d+)\.&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;([^-]+) - (.*)/
var matches = str.match(regex);
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = matches[2] + " : " + matches[3];
```