# javascript extract substring from checkbox innput string value

Tags: javascript, checkbox

below a set of checkbox, I would like to retrieve the monetary value of the string from the box to consistent.

for example if the checkbox input value is "Vantaux inegaux maxi vantail 2150 mm $1021.2" i would get the 1021.2   .

here is my code but it returns an error when using .val()

> Uncaught TypeError: this.checked.val is not a function

[checkbox values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AMJ7r.png)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('input[type=checkbox]').change(function() {
    if(this.checked) {
      console.log (this.checked.val());
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" value="Vantaux inegaux maxi vantail 2150 mm $1021.2"/>
```

any suggestion please ?

Comment: `this.checked` is a boolean (primitive) attr.  That attribute doesn't provide any function.

Comment: What you want to do is either `this.value` or `$(this).val()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the `.checked` attribute "returns" a Boolean indicating if the checkbox is checked or not, so to get the value of the checked checkbox you'd use `.val()` method.

Here's a demo snippet to get the monetary value from the checked checkbox:

> As you're using `jQuery`, it's better to stick with `jQuery` objects, so, `this` should be wrapped in a `jQuery` object like this: `$(this)`.
>
> To see if the checkbox is checked or not, we'll use the `jQuery` `.is()` method.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('input[type=checkbox]').change(function() {
    if($(this).is(':checked')) {
      console.log (/\$(([\d]+)(:?\.[\d]+)?)/.exec($(this).val())[1]);
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" value="Vantaux inegaux maxi vantail 2150 mm $1021.2"/>
```

Hope I pushed you further.

Comment: Glad I managed to help you. I advice you to recheck my answer as I just edited it to include some explanations.

Answer (score 1):

In your case: `this` is not refering to a jQuery object, it is refering directly to an HTMLElement, so to use `val()` you need to use `$(this).val()`, but it is not necessary because you can simply use `this.value`

**NOTE:**

 `this.checked` holds a boolean value, true or false, it didn't have any `value` attribute, so don't use it like `this.checked.value`, it will be `undefined`.

Working example:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('input[type=checkbox]').change(function() {
    if(this.checked) {
      console.log (this.value);
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" value="Vantaux inegaux maxi vantail 2150 mm $1021.2"/>
```

Comment: it works and how coudl i extract the value 170.2 from the string " Coulissant imitation à 2 vantaux $170.2" , have u an idea ?

Comment: It depends, if you know exactly that you want the `170.2` you can go by this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18290599/extract-part-of-the-string

Comment: If you don't know the value, just know that it comes after `$` then it is a little harder and should be asked in another question, not in comments. If my answer helped and answered your original question. please consider to mark it as accepted

Answer (score 0):

if you are sure that the price is always last, you should split the string at the "$" and take the last element of the array:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('input[type=checkbox]').change(function() {
    if(this.checked) {     
      console.log (this.value.split("$").pop());
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<input type="checkbox" value="Vantaux inegaux maxi vantail 2150 mm $1021.2"/>
```

but if i were you, and if ill have control over the check box creation, ill put a data attribute like: `data-pricevalue` when you create the checkbox, and then get that value from there

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('input[type=checkbox]').change(function() {
    if(this.checked) {
      console.log(this.getAttribute('data-pricevalue'));     
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" data-pricevalue="1021.2" value="Vantaux inegaux maxi vantail 2150 mm $1021.2"/>
```

or may be think why the value on the check has all that text instead of just the value and put all that text on a label or something

```html
<input type="checkbox" value="1021.2"/>Vantaux inegaux maxi vantail 2150 mm $1021.2
```

edit: if coment was a question, ill do somthin like:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

function sumChecked()
{
var $totalSpan = $("#totalSum");
var totalSum = 0.0;
$( "input:checked" ).each(function() {
  totalSum = totalSum + parseFloat(this.value);  
  });
  $totalSpan.html(totalSum);
}

  $('input[type=checkbox]').change(function() {    
      sumChecked();    
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" value="1021.2"/>Vantaux inegaux maxi vantail 2150 mm $1021.2</br>
<input type="checkbox" value="901.8"/>Vantaux inegaux maxi vantail 1850 mm $901.8</br>
<input type="checkbox" value="800.5"/>Vantaux inegaux maxi vantail 1000 mm $800.5</br>


Total:<span id="totalSum"> </span>
```

Comment: yeah it works well , could now update the content of the span below : span new content = old content + x ; x is a number .                                                       <span id="our_price_display" class="price" itemprop="price" content="2042.4">2 042,40 €</span>

Comment: is this a question? sorry, very basic english here, if it is, ill create a function to sum all cheked elements (if you have many) and change the html of the span